# How to add google DNS Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dns

Blockquote

I want to add google DNS but i can't find the `nameservers` part in my config file
this is the `netplan` directory

[netplan folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKK6P.png)

but when i open the `01-network-manager-all.yaml` to edit i can't find name spaces part as described here
[01-network-manager-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BLY.png)

**Knowing that my connection is via WIFI**

So, How can i add google dns?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this method](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/)?

Comment: Or this? https://www.liberiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/google_dns_provider_1_thumb.png

Comment: @KGIII i have seen it but when i want to edit my nameservers i didn't find it

Comment: @chili555 **my connection is via WIFI**

Comment: Look in Settings > WiFi and select your connection, for example *mylilrouter* and click the gear symbol next to it. Then, under the IPv4 tab, set your DNS nameservers: https://i.postimg.cc/VLDNm5wK/Screenshot-from-2021-01-14-08-42-35.png